# Input Output shapes in 3D Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensor

I am trying to predict the **fluid flow (CFD)** in 3d grid. How do I resolve the shape issue for 3D CNN using TensorFlow Keras? My data is in array format, converted from 3D voxels of size `26x26x25` (each position has binary intersection values).

The sample dataset I using :

| xi | yi | zi | Intersection | Pressure | xo | yo | zo | VectorLengths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 13.884494 | -0.703813 | 2.466158 | 0.018699 | 2.56469 |
| 48.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 14.258714 | -0.88888 | 2.468673 | 0.022123 | 2.623918 |
| 52.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 14.896428 | -1.111264 | 2.419427 | 0.027871 | 2.662576 |
| 56.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 17.452873 | -1.681988 | 2.014204 | 0.024884 | 2.624256 |
| 60.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 18.358311 | -1.997472 | 1.729148 | -0.012313 | 2.641968 |
| 64.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 25.605123 | -1.422803 | 0.838155 | -0.051405 | 1.652125 |
| 68.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 27.079014 | -0.609079 | 0.970788 | -0.016893 | 1.146164 |
| 72.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 24.689617 | -0.531884 | 1.25762 | 0.070454 | 1.367287 |
| 76.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 24.232602 | -0.740082 | 1.471623 | 0.082383 | 1.649297 |
| 80.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 24.534561 | -0.948655 | 1.486321 | 0.070399 | 1.764668 |
| 84.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 25.462308 | -1.107409 | 1.368035 | 0.067043 | 1.761354 |
| 88.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 26.770422 | -1.196752 | 1.175512 | 0.069665 | 1.678957 |
| 92.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 28.244122 | -1.219478 | 0.959174 | 0.076455 | 1.553379 |
| 96.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 29.742913 | -1.192564 | 0.749664 | 0.086819 | 1.411291 |
| 100.026235 | 117.742061 | 2 | 1 | 31.159956 | -1.132304 | 0.554855 | 0.093398 | 1.264396 |

The inputs are : xi,yi,zi and Intersection ; The outputs are : Pressure,xo,yo,zo and VectorLengths

I **reshaped** the feature and label arrays this way :

```
features=tf.reshape(features, [133, 26, 26, 25, 4])
labels=tf.reshape(labels, [133, 26, 26, 25, 5])
```

The CNN model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), input_shape=(26, 26, 25, 4), activation='relu'))
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2))
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=5, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(features, labels, epochs = 25)
```

The error I am getting:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_52 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 16900]

Any ideas what I am getting wrong? Also please suggest if using 3D CNN for this dataset is the right approach or there are other approaches we should try?

Comment: Make sure that the `features` are getting reshaped before using them in `model.fit()`. Also, is there a special reason to use `tf.reshape`?

Comment: You need to move the Flatten layer between the `GlobalAveragePooling3D` and the `Dense(units=64, activation="relu")`.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal  , I did reshape the features before model fitting, and used tf.reshape to get the correct data shape for 3d conv nets.

Comment: @aim97 I tried to add the flatten layer between the mentioned layers, still having the error.

Comment: Binary crossentropy is used for binary classification but your output has 5 classes,  try using sparse categorical crossentropy instead. Also try to add names to your layers so the error message would tell us which layer has the problem in a more readable way.

Comment: `GlobalAveragePooling3D` expects 5D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, spatial_dim1, spatial_dim2, spatial_dim3, channels)`. Reshape your data properly. Conv3D also expects 5D input. Make sure input shape is 5D. Since its not binary classification use sparse_ctegorical crossentropy. Thanks!